# Volume of an ellipsoid using Gauss' Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, ellipsoids

> **Question:**
>
> Let $F= (0,0,z)$ be a vector field.
>
> Use Gauss' Divergence Theorem to calculate the volume of the ellipsoid $x^2+y^2+2z^2=1$

**My attempt:**

$$r(a,b) = (\cos(a)\cos(b),\cos(a)\sin(b), \frac{\sin(a)}{\sqrt{2}})$$

where $a\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] , b\in [0,2\pi]$

I assume I must calculate $$\iint_SF \cdot \hat n \space  dS= \iint_S F(r(a,b) \cdot (r_a \text{x} r_b) dadb$$

Is this a correct method?

Thank you

Comment: Pretty close. That's a relatively clever parameterization of the surface that seems to avoid having to deal with the top and bottom halves separately. When you are done, you can compare with the mensuration formula $$V=\frac{4\pi}3abc=\frac{4\pi}3(1)(1)(\frac1{\sqrt2})$$

Comment: What does it mean if I got $-\frac{4\pi}3(\frac1{\sqrt2})$?

Comment: Probably means that when you took $$\begin{align}d^2\vec A&=\pm\langle-\sin a\cos b,-\sin a\sin b,\frac{\cos a}{\sqrt2}\rangle\,da\times\langle-\cos a\sin b,\cos a\sin b,0\rangle\,db\\&=\pm\langle-\frac{\cos^2a\cos b}{\sqrt2},-\frac{\cos^2a\sin b}{\sqrt2},-\sin a\cos a\rangle\,da\,db\end{align}$$ That you didn't take into account that for $0\le a\le\frac{\pi}2$ the outward normal should point **up** so the $z$-component should be positive and that $\pm$ should be $-$.

Comment: Thank you for that. Apart from that, is everything else correct?

Comment: Well, your final answer is correct, but I can't vouch for the intermediate miracles. I imagine that you found $$\int\int\int\vec\nabla\cdot\vec Fd^3V=\int\int\int1\,d^3V=V$$ so that you could apply the divergence theorem?